# How to detect node name changes in Maya

Tags: c++, nodes, rename, maya

I am working on c++ plugin for maya and need to detect when some nodes get renamed by the user in the Outliner.

I could find a addNameChangedCallback function in MNodeMessage, but it is stated as obsolete. What non-obsolete message callback could I use ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking to some old documentation and autodesk decided to keep that method please check this http://help.autodesk.com/view/MAYAUL/2016/ENU/?guid=__cpp_ref_class_m_node_message_html

Comment: Indeed, your link gave me better information on how to use it. Thanks !